# How to capture stdout of remote celery worker?

Tags: python, stdout, celery

I have a setup with multiple remote Celery workers. In the main program which is starting tasks via apply_async I need continuous access to stdout of active remote workers.

Is it possible using only Celery API?

Answer (score 1):

I think you should set up your [SysLogHandler](http://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.handlers.html#sysloghandler). [CELERY_REDIRECT_STDOUTS](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/configuration.html#celery-redirect-stdouts) and [CELERY_REDIRECT_STDOUTS_LEVEL](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/configuration.html#celery-redirect-stdouts-level) are working by default with current logger.

You can try example so (on remote servert):

> ```
> import logging
> from logging.handlers import SysLogHandler
>
> logger = logging.getLogger()
> logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
> # host is your server that used for the log
> syslog = SysLogHandler(address=(host, port))
> formatter = logging.Formatter('%(name)s: %(levelname)s %(message)s')
> syslog.setFormatter(formatter)
> logger.addHandler(syslog)
>
> # check it
> logger.info("Test test")
> ```