# Redirecting stdout in Celery

Tags: python, celery

I have a simple Celery task that looks like this:

```
@celery.task
   def tail():
   cmd = 'nslookup www.google.com'
   cm = shlex.split(cmd)
   out = subprocess.check_output(cm)
   print out
```

Which outputs something like this when the task is executed by the Worker:

```
[2013-12-02 23:54:26,007: WARNING/Worker-2] 
Server:             192.168.1.254
Address:        192.168.1.254#53
Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   www.google.com
Address: 173.194.34.112
Name:   www.google.com
Address: 173.194.34.113
Name:   www.google.com
Address: 173.194.34.115
Name:   www.google.com
Address: 173.194.34.114
Name:   www.google.com
Address: 173.194.34.116
[2013-12-02 23:54:26,008: INFO/MainProcess] Task app.tail[23f625f7-d328-47c5-8f57-    90a330ebe100] succeeded in 0.0618259499897s: None
```

I need the celery task to capture the stdout for each line so that I can redirect it and store it elsewhere.

I can see in the Celery docs http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/reference/celery.app.log.html?highlight=stdout#celery.app.log.Logging.redirect_stdouts the options for defining loggers and redirecting stdout, however I can't work out how to wire it up!

Suggestions would be much appreciated!

Regards.

Answer (score -2):

This is not really related to celery, if you want to execute a command while capturing the output you should execute it differently.

Take a look at the Subprocess module: http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html

Specifically, the part about capturing `stderr` since it's not writing to `stdout` :)

```
import celery
import subprocess

@celery.task
def tail():
    process = subprocess.Popen('nslookup www.google.com', shell=True, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
    print 'Stdout: ', process.stdout
    print 'Stderr: ', process.stderr
```

Comment: Hmm - I thought that this "redirect_stdouts_to_logger(logger, loglevel=None, stdout=True, stderr=True)[source]
Redirect sys.stdout and sys.stderr to a logging instance" was supposed to do that. This post also eludes to the fact it can be done http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17549598/how-to-capture-stdout-of-remote-celery-worker

Comment: It can be done, but it's definitely not the best way of doing it. There is a good chance you'll accidently capture extra output from other processes.

Comment: So can I just capture the Celery log entry ?

Comment: Well... in theory, if you create your own log handler than you could capture the celery log entries. But it'll be hard to get to work reliably since multiple threads/eventlets can log to the same loghandler.

Comment: Hmm - So would be the best way to achieve this? All I need is to capture some of the log events to a separate DB.

Comment: As I said, use the subprocess module to capture the output from the program. After that you can write it to the database. I'll add an example of how to capture the output. Although in this case (if you're just trying to do dns lookups, you might want to use a library like dnspython instead (http://www.dnspython.org/)

Comment: Thanks - No I'm no just doing DNS lookups that was an example only. My  process will need to call the command line - unfortunately !

Comment: The question is about how to connect to Celery's logging. This answer doesn't help.

Comment: @John he was having trouble because he wasn't capturing the subprocess output, it wasn't a celery logging issue so it most certainly is relevant to the question.

Comment: Writing `print 'Stdout: ', process.stdout` doesn't 'capture the subprocess output', @Wolph. That snippet would just block the child process execution; there is nothing reading the output.