# unicode in celery (python 2.7)

Tags: python, python-2.7, celery

I'm using celery 4.1 in flask. (python 2.7)

```
print(u'glätteisen')
```

the code is working in flask. but when I try this code inside celery, that doesn't print anything.

```
print('something')
```

when I try this, this is printed.
what is wrong ?

Comment: Hm, my guess: This is not related to unicode, but rather to how celery handles what goes to stdout. Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17549598/how-to-capture-stdout-of-remote-celery-worker this might help.

Comment: when I try print('something') in celery, this is printed. I'm running celery loglevel to debug.